# Error when trying to retrieve value from a property of a nested object using VueJS Interpolation

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I'm having trouble displaying an array inside of an array in Vue JS. This is my JSON:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "slug": "test-page",
  "banner": {
    "title": "banner title",
    "subTitle": "my sub title",
    "hasSubTitle": false,
    "hasClass": "jumbotron-houses jumbotron-page"
  },
  "pageTitle": "Test Page",
  "pageDescription": "My Page Description",
  "content": "<h1>test</h1>"
}
```

I'd like to show the banner Title and each individual banner elements. I've tried:

```
{{ page.banner['title'] }}
```

What am I missing? This doesn't work?

Also tried:

```
{{ page.banner[0] }}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`banner` is not an array.

Try this instead:

```
{{ page.banner.title }}
```

---

**demo**

```js
var page = {
  "id": 1,
  "slug": "test-page",
  "banner": {
    "title": "banner title",
    "subTitle": "my sub title",
    "hasSubTitle": false,
    "hasClass": "jumbotron-houses jumbotron-page"
  },
  "pageTitle": "Test Page",
  "pageDescription": "My Page Description",
  "content": "<h1>test</h1>"
};

document.body.innerText = page.banner.title;
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. My data is coming from an external URL, an API in JSON format, I get: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You should check how many objects you received from your Api call. If there is more than one you must use a v-for for each of them or if there is only one you must use

```
{{ page[0].banner.title }}
```

Also check the name **page** if it is currect.

```js
var page = [{
  "id": 1,
  "slug": "test-page",
  "banner": {
    "title": "banner title",
    "subTitle": "my sub title",
    "hasSubTitle": false,
    "hasClass": "jumbotron-houses jumbotron-page"
  },
  "pageTitle": "Test Page",
  "pageDescription": "My Page Description",
  "content": "<h1>test</h1>"
},
];

document.body.innerText = page[0].banner.title;
```